# C# Webbrowser not loading full web page - page loaded event handler

Tags: c#, events, webbrowser-control, domdocument

I have a [webpage that I want to monitor](https://www.bdswiss.com/en/trade) that has stock market information that I want to read and store. The information gathered is to be stored somewhere, say a .csv file or similar for later analysis.

The first problem I have is detecting when this page has fully loaded. The time taken to load can vary enormously. The event handlers I have tried all fire multiple times (I know this has been covered and I have tried the various techniques, but to no avail). Perhaps it is something specific to do with this web-page? Anyway, I need to know when this page has fully loaded and is sitting pretty with all graphics displayed properly.

The second problem is that, I cannot get the true source page into the webbrowser. As as a consequence, all access to the DOM fails as the HTML representation inside the webbrowser control appears not match what is actually happening on the webpage. I have dumped the text (`webBrowser2.DocumentText`) and it looks nothing like what you see when I check source in a browser, chrome for example. (I also use the firebug extension in Firefox to double check things). How can I get to the correct page into the webbrowser so I can start to manipulate things?

Essentially, in terms of the data, I need the GMT Time, Strike Rate and expiration time. My process will monitor with a timer control. To be able to read all the other element data on screen is a nice-to-have.

Can this be done?

I am an experienced programmer new to web programming and C#.

Comment: That's pretty obvious when you use a regular browser to navigate to that page.  It was made for eyeballs and programmers that like writing programs for people with eyeballs.  The latter ones have to pay for the information, the point of publishing it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want [this AJAX request](https://spotplatform.bancdeswiss.com/PlatformAjax/getJsonFile/platformGraph/regular/binary/-60minutes/now/asset/91/2/graphData.spotgraph).

As a review, the web works by first loading the web page, then scanning the web page for additional files it needs to load (js, css, images, etc).  When those finish, the `onload` event is triggered and some AJAX functions may run.

In this case, only some of the page is loaded and AJAX functions update the data in the graph later.  As you've seen "Show Source" only shows the original file that was downloaded and is *not* a dump of its current state.

The easiest way to get the data is to find the URL of the AJAX request that loads the graph data.  It is already conveniently formatted in JSON for you to scrap.